# Kill all sessions when are multiple sessions ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm looking for a method to kill all session of my site when the user has my site in multiple tabs. I tried to set `online=1` in database and after when user wants to login again check if the `online=1` and kill the sessions, but this doesn't work always. Does anybody know a method to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to kill all sessions if user wants to use multiple tabs? Apart from that, have you tried `Session.Clear()` or `Session.Abandon()`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to *prevent*?  How are you going to know if the user is using multiple tabs, or multiple private browsing sessions, or multiple web browsers, or multiple machines, etc.?

Comment: I have a timer on my site which insert in database the time spent on site and if 2 tabs are opened this timer insert 2 x  time spent on site.Thanks

Comment: Ok i can use Session.Clear() or Session.Abandon()  , but how to find when  are more than 1 tab opened ?

Comment: @AlexSlusar: what's the problem with multiple tabs or browsers? That absolutely none of your business. To repeat David: what exactly are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter, On my site i have a timer which count the time spent on site and if the same page is opened in multiple tabs this timer multiply the time.Thanks

Comment: @AlexSlusar: then you should fix that bug instead. But we cannot help since you haven't provided any code.

Comment: @AlexSlusar If you want to track time spent on the site, stopping users from using multiple tabs or browsers is a bad solution as it adversely affects the user experience. A better solution might be to calculate the time between login and session end or logout, perhaps with some sort of timer that resets on each page load if you want to track active use.

Comment: Why not just track page loads?!

Answer (score 1):

you have to put this code in final your code or when you want user to logout

```
Session.Clear();
```